# How is Bob meant to obtain Cameron’s contact address for Data Protection concerns?

Tags: england-and-wales, gdpr, data-protection

[Cameron](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/98575/is-cameron-a-data-controller/98580#98580) is almost certainly a data controller for the prose of the the UKGDPR.

How can Bob practically go about seeking recourse and a means to reach Cameron, or an address on which to serve correspondence on him, when Cameron might not even know what the GDPR is, or may be an anarchist punk or self proclaimed sovereign citizen who would prefer not to be accountable to legal duties, and may have a personal practice of militantly refusing to give his own contact/identifying details, whether to police, or to data subjects?

What is Bob legally supposed to do in case Cameron scoffs in his face at his queries, or completely ignores him?

Comment: The anarchist punks I know are stricter with personal information than the GDPR.

Comment: lol you’re right in some cases. Guess it depends on whether they have most freshly in their minds a zine about consent or security culture.

Comment: "*What is Bob legally supposed to do...*". Does GPDR impose any obligation on Bob?  I.e. is he "supposed" to do anything, or does he have an option to pursue action or not?  Because if not, "does Bob have a right to detain Cameron" might be a better phrasing of the legal challenge he faces with a non compliant punk.

Comment: The implied part is “what is Bob supposed to do by the law if he wishes to exercise his data rights”?

Comment: Then you should edit to clarify it is asking a GPDR specific procedural question.  Because the question (and first comment on the answer...) can be paraphrased as "*what if a stranger won't give me their address and phone number when i ask them?*". And that same question could apply to an attempt to gather personal information to report someone for littering.

Answer (score 3):

### Go to the regulator

Each EU country plus the UK has a government organisation responsible for ensuring compliance with the GDPR.

Comment: And say what, “I’d like to complain against the balaclava wearing member of a black bloc demonstration whose name and address I don’t know?

Comment: @TylerDurden, how about: "I would like to complain against the data controller of Cameron.blogs.example.com. Unfortunately they refuse to give me contact details."

Comment: What if you haven’t encountered the published photos online but would like to know how/where the taken photos will be stored/processed/published?

Comment: Ask the photographer politely.  Really Tyler, you are asking for personal advice on how to deal with a difficult person.  That isn't a legal question.

Comment: @TylerDurden if you have a follow up question about identifying someone you’d like to legally pursue or report, ask that question. But check the stack first - I think it’s already been asked.

Comment: @MichaelHall I firmly disagree: the law is usually about giving people recourse to when people are unreasonable, difficult, or shirking their responsibilities assigned thereby.

Comment: There is absolutely no legal recourse for when someone is being unreasonable or difficult.